# Aplicación se detiene después de descargarla

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación, pero cuando los usuarios la descargan desde Google Play Store en varios telefonos la aplicación queda una pantalla negra y luego muestra el mensaje indicando que la app se a detenido, he buscado la causa de este problema pero aun no la encuentro.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'TCL/5042A/Alto45:4.4.4/KTU84P/v2CV0-0:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 5862, tid: 5862, name: devitech.nmtaxi  >>> com.devitech.nmtaxi <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 43c3c338  r1 417d2ba8  r2 417d2ba8  r3 5884d000
    r4 58678aae  r5 57529c54  r6 414f67e8  r7 00000002
    r8 00000000  r9 617ca8c9  sl 417d28f8  fp 00000049
    ip 617ca8ad  sp beefe438  lr 617cada1  pc 617c9ef0  cpsr 600f0030
    d0  0020006c0061003a  d1  006e006700690000
    d2  0020006e00690020  d3  00650064006f0000
    d4  007300740074002e  d5  007200650073002e
    d6  0065006300690076  d7  006f006f0047002e
    d8  000000204343ac00  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 4035000000000000  d17 4035800000000000
    d18 0000000000000000  d19 3ffe453060000000
    d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
    d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
    d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    d26 3feffffff194958b  d27 0000000000000000
    d28 400ca25040000000  d29 0000000000000000
    d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 68000013

backtrace:
    #00  pc 0003aef0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
    #01  pc 0003bd9d  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

code around pc:
    617c9ed0 606819c4 f85f0088 68010008 60013101  
    617c9ee0 f8df69a8 b31810b4 42916802 8003f040  
    617c9ef0 616b6883 69a8e024 0718f2a5 c701b1d8  
    617c9f00 409cf8df a211a108 e932f7c5 e012e01e  
    617c9f10 29006af8 f8dfdc04 ea4f7084 47b80106  
    617c9f20 f7c5a101 e006e8ba 616c6934 de00e008  
    617c9f30 006cf8df f8dfe001 6ef10068 1c2d4788  
    617c9f40 4300e320 47806f70 58678ad0 0000e7fe  
    617c9f50 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000100  
    617c9f60 00000000 00000000 57873288 00160001  
    617c9f70 00000001 58719918 00000000 00000000  
    617c9f80 00000000 5786e108 00000000 00190101  
    617c9f90 00000001 00000001 417d2ba8 4157e7c1  
    617c9fa0 58678ac8 606819c8 f85f0034 68010008  
    617c9fb0 60013101 102af896 0000f04f b9316068  
    617c9fc0 0200ea4f f7c56132 e003e830 f8dfde00  

code around lr:
    617cad80 f85f0028 68010008 60013101 b9286828  
    617cad90 4300e000 47806e70 58678ab4 f8a0f7ff  
    617cada0 47806e70 58678ac8 00000002 00000000  
    617cadb0 00000000 57873288 000a0101 00000001  
    617cadc0 00000000 60681a3c f85f005c 68010008  
    617cadd0 60013101 b1e86868 f3bf6a41 f8df8f5f  
    617cade0 ea4f206c 60290001 6801b160 3058f8df  
    617cadf0 0001f04f f0004291 ea4f8005 ea4f0001  
    617cae00 47980102 0200ea4f 60286132 e90cf7c4  
    617cae10 de00e003 002cf8df f8dfe001 6ef10024  
    617cae20 00004788 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    617cae30 579bbdb8 00000103 00000001 00000000  
    617cae40 5fc4d5c0 5fc4d5b8 41567959 41a50c40  
    617cae50 60681a40 f85f0078 68010008 60013101  
    617cae60 00b4f8df 20acf8df 0c08f845 00a0f8df  
    617cae70 0101f04f b9184790 009cf8df ea24f7c4
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consola es lo mismo que comente aquí, cabe aclarar que tengo 4 años desarrollando en Android y nunca me tope con este error.

Comment: Lo que agregas no indica nada, busca en el StackTace lo puedes ver en  la pantalla que indica el error. Que aplicación es, si se puede saber

Comment: La aplicacion es NMTaxi la encuentras en google play, ese error me sale en la consola de desarrolladores cuando se notifica el error desde el movil.

Comment: En Android 7.0 no se muestra, en otros si funciona, mejor revisa dentro de la consola de desarrollo el stacktrace ya que esta info no dice mucho,

Comment: Eso es lo que me tiene loco buscando una solucion, esta es la unica información que tengo y la tome de la consola de google play porque en el log de android studio no me muestra nada

Comment: Ve la actualización de mi respuesta! espero puedas entrar y ver más información

Comment: Donde veo la actualizacion ??? jajaja, disculpa soy nuevo aqui XD.

Comment: ve mi respuesta.... @Zait_Paulo

Answer (score 0):

Te comento primeramente que en Android 7.0 no se soporta, pero lo tienen validado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de tu consola de desarrollo ve a `Crashes & ANRs` > `STACK TRACES` y agrega en tu pregunta la descripción del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En base a lo que obtienes se deduce que el dispositivo es un :

Android "NOS Roya" con Android 4.4

Comment: Si ese error sale mayormente en esos dispositivos